# Is there an easy way to create elastic game objects and get relative coordinates?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

Lets say I have the following game object hierarchy:

- `Board` - The entire view of the game's board, made up of tiles.
- `Tile` - A rectangular boundary within a board, made up of subtiles.
- `Subtile` - A rectangular boundary within a tile.

A `Board` needs relative **dimensions** with respect to all of the contained `Tile` objects.

A `Tile` needs relative **coordinates** with respect to the containing `Board`.

A `Subtile` needs relative **coordinates** with respect to the containing `Tile`.

My current process is to define `n` `Tile` objects. Space them out `x` and `y`, such that `x` is the number of `Subtile` objects in a row and `y` is the number of `Subtile` objects in a column. Then, when I place `Subtile` objects, I just multiple the `x` or `y` by the containing `Tile` object's starting coordinate.

This process, so far, works well enough. However, to avoid complication and errors, I'd love to be able to simply lay out a `Subtile` object, where (0, 0) would be the top-left of the `Tile` object.

Without just abstracting my positioning a bit and adding classes for, say, `SubtileVector` or something, which would keep an additional variable for offset relative tile, is there an easier way to do this?

Likewise, when I want to see how big my board is and center my camera in the middle of it, I just end up calculating to that position. Is there any way to have my board always act as the containing box for these tiles, and be able to just do something like `Board.Position.Center` and get the exact center coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. You can make a **board** game object, parent it to **tile** game objects, who on their turn are parent to **subtile** objects:

Board, parent to
      Tile, parent to
         Subtile

The good news is you can use the relative coordinates of tile and subtile using using their

```
transform.localPosition
```

Comment: Can't believe I was so blind that I missed localPosition on the 16th. This has been amazing for me since then, sorry I haven't commented. Accepting your answer since this the solution.